# Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 and -webkit-tap-highlight-color style for tr/td onclick event?

Tags: android, onclick, galaxy-tab

```
<table width=100% style="border:#d9d9d9 2px solid;margin-bottom:10px;background:#ffffff">
   <tr>
      <td height=80 width=100% valign=center onclick="javascript:alert('dsfasdfds');">sdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd
   </tr>
</table>
```

When I click the web page,the highlighting works great on most devices, but not on my Galaxy Tab 10.1.

I hope to always get the 'highlight' on the `td` or `tr` tag.

Comment: samsung Galaxy sII mobile is ok.but Galaxy Tab 10.1 and Galaxy note 10.1 no 'highlight'.

Comment: i have created a app with html/javascript with phonegap. My problem is that when tr/td tag get clicked they show the orange highlight.but Galaxy Tab 10.1 and Galaxy note 10.1 not work